# Flushing early with GZIP enabled on IIS6

Tags: iis-6, gzip, flush

I'm using classic ASP on IIS6 and am trying to following YSlow's recommendation to flush the content early, just after the page header.
If compression is disabled then this works a treat, the browser starts downloading the css and images from the header before the rest of the page is received.
However, if compression is enabled in IIS (either gzip or deflate) then the browser waits until all the content has been received before downloading any of the other items from the page, I'm using Chrome and Firefox to test this.

I have read it's possible do flush early with compression enabled in Apache, does anyone know if it's possible to do this with IIS6?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this, I managed to resolve it by lowering the gzip compression level for dynamic content from 9 to 3.
Obviously this means more data to download, but it isn't that much and seeing as our CDN provider also compresses the content I decided it was worth implementing.